# CSS for Nested Lists

Tags: html, css, nested-lists, html-lists

I am currently trying to create some nested lists to display the following...

A...R...X

B...S...Y

C...T...Z

(where the letters will eventually be replaced by words) and have made this work perfectly in chrome and firefox, however when I use Internet Explorer I get something resembling the following...

A
B...R
C...S...X
......T...Y
...........Z

I assume it's probably to do with the css, but please can someone help me with this problem, the html and css are shown below, thanks in advance for any help.

HTML

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<link rel=stylesheet href="lists in IE.css" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>

<div id="container">

    <ul id="links-nav">
        <li>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">A</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">B</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">C</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">L</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">M</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">N</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">X</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Y</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Z</a></li>
            </ul>       
        </li>

    </ul>

    <div class="clear"></div>   
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

CSS

```
#container{
    width:940px; 
    margin:0px auto; 
    border: 1px solid #000;
    padding: 20px 10px; 
    height:auto; 
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif; 
    font-size:11px;
}

.clear {
    clear: both;
    height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}


a{
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#555;
}

#links-nav li, li ul li{
    list-style:none;
}

#links-nav{
    list-style-type: none;  
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
}

#links-nav li ul{
    float:left;
    width:168px;
    padding: 0px 10px;
    list-style-type: none;      
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add in your css

```
#links-nav > li {
    width:168px;
    float:left;
}
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/qUJuy/2/

or

```
#links-nav > li {
    width:168px;
    display:inline;
}
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/qUJuy/3/

The above will fix the error in ie7 (in ie8 it was already correct).

Comment: That has worked brilliantly thank you, I have found that now IE is adding extra padding within the bottom of the container div, do you know how to stop IE adding this padding?

Comment: @Phil it's need to clear the floats. Add `overflow:hidden` for `#links-nav`

Comment: target IE with conditional comments and set padding to 0